# how use provisioning profile ios to get an IPA file

Tags: iphone, ios, trigger.io, testflight

I have a valid IOS dev certificate and profile as I can seefrom XCode
[image]

I have a mobile app working and I d like to create a IOS package - a IPA file that I'd like to test on my iPhone using TestFlight.

What I need to insert in my Trigger.io tool kit > Toold > Profile ?

Comment: In your Xcode->Product->Archiving.It will create your ipa file.

Comment: Solved it out....I was trying to obtain ipa file with Trigger.io not xcode..answer below - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can search for it in the apple support page. How to create an IPA file is explained quite clear in the 'Creating an iOS App Store Package' section:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1

Comment: I he ve already my profile...in Trigger.io in tools session is aking to put profile ...I'm not sure what I have type in there?

Comment: It seems you have solved it like you've said below. I'm happy you've found the way.

Answer (score 1):

Solve out I think (not sure cos I stilll have to test my .api)
I have give the path to my ios profile and where it asking profile just the name of my profile ios file.
That gave me error in Trigger.io output but apparently I have my .api file in release directory.